# Error when building Chromium on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, chromium, ninja

I'm using Windows 7 with SP1 and Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3. I followed [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md) instruction step by step.

#### Setting up the build:

By Visual Studio Command Prompt I type:

```
gn gen --target_cpu="x86" --filters=//chrome out\Default
```

Then I type:

```
ninja -C out\Default chrome
```

And when compilation is about 10% done, the build fails with missing file.

#### Full log:

```
D:\ChromiumBuild\chromium\src>gn gen --target_cpu="x86" --filters=//chrome o
t\Default
Done. Made 5575 targets from 1215 files in 3469ms

D:\ChromiumBuild\chromium\src>ninja -C out\Default chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out\Default'
[2762/27638] ACTION //third_party/WebK...ue_keywords(//build/toolchain/win:x64)
FAILED: gen/blink/core/CSSValueKeywords.cpp gen/blink/core/CSSValueKeywords.h
D:/Chromium/depot_tools/python276_bin/python.exe ../../third_party/WebKit/Sourc
/build/scripts/make_css_value_keywords.py ../../third_party/WebKit/Source/core/
ss/CSSValueKeywords.in ../../third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/SVGCSSValueKeyw
rds.in --output_dir gen/blink/core --gperf ../../third_party/gperf/bin/gperf.ex

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../third_party/WebKit/Source/build/scripts/make_css_value_keywords.p
", line 177, in <module>
    in_generator.Maker(CSSValueKeywordsWriter).main(sys.argv)
  File "D:\ChromiumBuild\chromium\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\build\scripts\i
_generator.py", line 108, in main
    writer.write_files(options.output_dir)
  File "D:\ChromiumBuild\chromium\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\build\scripts\i
_generator.py", line 60, in write_files
    self._write_file_if_changed(output_dir, generator(), file_name)
  File "../../third_party/WebKit/Source/build/scripts/make_css_value_keywords.p
", line 172, in generate_implementation
    gperf = subprocess.Popen(gperf_args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subproce
s.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
  File "D:\Chromium\depot_tools\python276_bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in
_init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Chromium\depot_tools\python276_bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in
execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[2771/27638] ACTION //third_party/WebK...ual_modules(//build/toolchain/win:x64)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

D:\ChromiumBuild\chromium\src>
```

I also tried without targeting x86:

```
gn gen --filters=//chrome out\Default
```

But problem is the same.

When I try creating solution and then compile in Visual Studio:

```
gn gen --ide=vs --filters=//chrome out\Default
devenv out\Default\all.sln
```

Building seems to have no end. After 4 hours compilation is about 20% done (16 GB RAM and 8 x 4.0 GHz with 100% CPU usage all the time, no antivirus or firewall).

Is there way to fix this missing file?